# will upgrading ubuntu to 16.04 changes my Apache, Mysql and Php version?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

Will Upgrading my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04 changes my Apache, Mysql and Php Versions?
My Present versions are as follows:
Apache: 2.4
Mysql: 5.5
Php: 5.5
If yes, to which version?

Comment: How did you install these?

Comment: individually... by apt-get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, to some degree. xenial comes with:

- apache2 - 2.4.18
- mysql-server - 5.7.17
- php - 7.0

EDIT:

according to @muru php5 packages might not get updated due to package name changes for php7. So I gave it a try:

installed a basic trusty and did

```
# apt-get install php5-cli php5 mysql-server

# dpkg -l | egrep "\s(apache2|php5|mysql-server)\s"
ii  apache2                          2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13                 amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  mysql-server                     5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1           all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  php5                             5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21            all          server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)

# sed -i 's/trusty/xenial/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get -y upgrade ; apt-get -y dist-upgrade
# apt-get --purge autoremove ; apt-get autoclean

# dpkg -l | egrep "\s(apache2|php5-cli|php-cli|mysql-server|mariadb-server)\s"
ii  apache2                          2.4.18-2ubuntu3.1                 amd64        Apache HTTP Server
ii  mysql-server                     5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1           all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  php5-cli                         5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.21            amd64        command-line interpreter for the php5 scripting language
```

So, @muru is right: php5 will most probably not be replaced even though the `php7.0-*` packages are defined with `Replaces: php5-cli (<< 5.6.16+dfsg-4~)` (for example).

Comment: Because of the package renaming, there's no direct connection between `php` on 16.04 and `php5` on 14.04 - so depending on how it was installed, PHP might not get upgraded at all.